# Sometimes I am unable to make the most simple cuts with knife

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

[image]

I am unable to cut a face with 4 vertices and a simple and "one-way going" topology.

I had issues with it before, so I had to cut something a couple of times before it worked. After I cut something I hit  <kbd>F</kbd> to delete the cut between 4 vertices, and then I cut it in half to make a crevice in the model.

The cut visible on the screen is impossible, whenever I try to cut it just doesn't do it.